# NelmioApiDocBundle how to pass a parameter to a form type classe in @ApiDoc (input) annotation?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a form used as a service which requires the service container as first param in constructor.

```
# in my services.yml file
    acme_foo_bundle.fish.form.type:
    class: Acme\FooBundle\Form\Type\FishType
    arguments: [@service_container]
    scope: request
```

Both : form and REST API are working well but when I browse the api doc (/app_dev.php/api/doc) it throws an error 500.

After investigations now I know that the error thrown because of the following lines in my rest controller :

```
 /**
 * in my rest controller file (postFishAction)
 * @ApiDoc(
 *   resource = true,
 *   input = "Acme\FooBundle\Form\Type\FishType",
 *   statusCodes = {
 *     200 = "Returned when successful",
 *     400 = "Returned when the form contains errors"
 *   }
 [...]
 */
 public function postFishAction(Request $request){ [...]
```

The problem is this line :

```
   input = "Acme\FooBundle\Form\Type\FishType",
```

it requires the service container as param and I don't know how to give it throught the @ApiDoc annotation.

Thanks for your help ✌

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with passing name of registered form type.

As doc says:

> **input:** the input type associated to the method (currently this supports Form Types, classes with JMS Serializer metadata, and classes with Validation component metadata) useful for POST|PUT methods, either as FQCN or **as form type** (if it is registered in the form factory in the container).
>   ```

so you should try something like this:

```
 /**
 * @ApiDoc(
 *   resource = true,
 *   input = "acme_foo_fish_type",
 *   statusCodes = {
 *     200 = "Returned when successful",
 *     400 = "Returned when the form contains errors"
 *   }
 [...]
 */
```

and your form type registration:

```
services:
    acme_foo_bundle.fish.form.type:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\Form\Type\FishType
        arguments: [@service_container]
        scope: request
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: acme_foo_fish_type }
```

and `FishType` must return `acme_foo_fish_type` in `getName` method.